# Samba not starting on Ubuntu Server 16.10

Tags: ubuntu, samba, ldap, kerberos, smb

Samba was running well on ubuntu server 14.04. After upgrading to 16.10 it doesn't start anymore. I've tried also to install samba on a fresh 16.10 vm and it doesn't work.

Here the service error message:

```
root@srvvm:~# systemctl restart smbd
Job for smbd.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status smbd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
root@srvvm:~# systemctl status smbd
● smbd.service - Samba SMB Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/smbd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2017-01-30 17:27:42 CET; 2s ago
     Docs: man:smbd(8)
           man:samba(7)
           man:smb.conf(5)
  Process: 3075 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/smbd $SMBDOPTIONS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 3075 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jan 30 17:27:42 srvvm systemd[1]: Starting Samba SMB Daemon...
Jan 30 17:27:42 srvvm smbd[3075]: [2017/01/30 17:27:42.769054,  0] ../source3/smbd/server.c:1441(main)
Jan 30 17:27:42 srvvm smbd[3075]:   server role = 'active directory domain controller' not compatible with running smbd standalone.
Jan 30 17:27:42 srvvm smbd[3075]:   You should start 'samba' instead, and it will control starting smbd if required
Jan 30 17:27:42 srvvm systemd[1]: smbd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 30 17:27:42 srvvm systemd[1]: Failed to start Samba SMB Daemon.
Jan 30 17:27:42 srvvm systemd[1]: smbd.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 30 17:27:42 srvvm systemd[1]: smbd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: It says "server role = 'active directory domain controller' not compatible with running smbd standalone." then to use

service samba start

There could also be issues with an incorrect /etc/samba/smb.conf, or missing samba/smb packages.

There should be a log in /var/log/samba/log.smbd to check as well.

Comment: It seems to be 16.10-specific. So I will not bother. Let's wait for 17.04

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue seems to persist in 17.04 (at least for me)

This worked for me:

```
sudo systemctl disable nmbd
sudo systemctl disable smbd
sudo systemctl unmask samba-ad-dc
sudo systemctl enable samba-ad-dc
```