# Samba not starting on Ubuntu Server 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, samba, domain

can't start samba

```
root@callserver:~# service smbd start
Job for smbd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status smbd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

root@callserver:~# systemctl status smbd.service
* smbd.service - Samba SMB Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/smbd.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2018-10-15 16:25:48 +06; 6s ago
     Docs: man:smbd(8)
           man:samba(7)
           man:smb.conf(5)
  Process: 21859 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/smbd $SMBDOPTIONS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 21859 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Oct 15 16:25:48 callserver systemd[1]: Starting Samba SMB Daemon...
Oct 15 16:25:48 callserver smbd[21859]: [2018/10/15 16:25:48.560635,  0] ../source3/smbd/server.c:1704(main)
Oct 15 16:25:48 callserver smbd[21859]:   server role = 'active directory domain controller' not compatible with running smbd standalone.
Oct 15 16:25:48 callserver smbd[21859]:   You should start 'samba' instead, and it will control starting smbd if required
Oct 15 16:25:48 callserver systemd[1]: smbd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 15 16:25:48 callserver systemd[1]: Failed to start Samba SMB Daemon.
Oct 15 16:25:48 callserver systemd[1]: smbd.service: Unit entered failed state.
Oct 15 16:25:48 callserver systemd[1]: smbd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step back one service level.  Solution is:

```
 service samba start
```

Comment: that dosent work root@callserver:~# service samba start
Failed to start samba.service: Unit samba.service not found.

Comment: error from smbd is misleading then. Try  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/359246/315887 solution. if that works I can update answer.

Comment: didnt work too /// root@callserver:~# service samba start
Failed to start samba.service: Unit samba.service not found./// did it step by step / //  sudo systemctl disable nmbd
sudo systemctl disable smbd
sudo systemctl unmask samba-ad-dc
sudo systemctl enable samba-ad-dc

Comment: [link](https://forum.ubuntu.ru/index.php?topic=242325.msg2360781#msg2360781)  there more information about my problem

Comment: Do you get different error?  Whats output from `systemctl list-unit-files | grep smb` command? Do we think its systemd/service issue or Samba configuration issue?  If this is smb.conf configuration problem ... I have used ROLE_STANDALONE and ROLE_DOMAIN_MEMBER successfully with this config (https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/samba-formula/blob/master/samba/defaults.yaml) but unfortunately not PDC ROLE so cannot help much with that.

Comment: root@callserver:~# systemctl list-unit-files | grep smb
smbd.service                               disabled //\\ different errors: root@callserver:~# smbclient //localhost/netlogon -UAdministrator -c 'ls'
Enter SRVR1\Administrator's password:
session setup failed: NT_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR

Comment: Whats output from `systemctl enable smbd` please?

Comment: root@callserver:~# systemctl enable smbd
Synchronizing state of smbd.service with SysV init with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install...
Executing /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable smbd
insserv: warning: current start runlevel(s) (empty) of script `smbd' overrides LSB defaults (2 3 4 5).
insserv: warning: current stop runlevel(s) (0 1 2 3 4 5 6) of script `smbd' overrides LSB defaults (0 1 6). //\\ thats it

Comment: and another root@callserver:~# smbclient //localhost/netlogon -UAdministrator -c 'ls'
Enter SRVR1\Administrator's password:
session setup failed: NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE

Comment: Run testparm (https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/testparm.1.html);

Comment: Run this: echo; echo "--";tail -20 /var/log/samba/log.smbd; echo "--"; ps -ef|grep mbd; echo "--"; pgrep -l samba; echo "--"; tail -20 /var/log/samba/log.nmbd ; echo "--"; dmesg | egrep "samba|mbd"; echo "--";
.

Comment: Consider samba reinstall too  (as sudo): apt-get purge samba; apt-get purge smbclient libsmbclient;apt-get purge samba-common;apt-get purge system-config-samba;apt-get install samba

Comment: Whats the output from `sestatus` command?

Comment: there is output of command testparm [testparm](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1CYGrKTIm-ilmvkYaCsNC8UcOEZHalEXNtXQ8BtsJrp8/edit?usp=sharing) and command echo

Comment: not found this command sestatus

Comment: and tooday in says [that](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1-j8UBNlE6fYpFv-MGE-04XSkQ3N_WSVJB9_pSz5W5P4/edit?usp=sharing) @nmclough

Comment: Thank you @АкжолМуратов . Add following line to your smb.conf 

`"idmap config * : range": 16777216-33554431 ` and keep running **testparm** until error goes away.  Check my reference smb.con [here](https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/samba-formula/blob/master/samba/defaults.yaml#L36) :